# Deleting asp:FileUpload elements makes jQuery File Upload not to work

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-file-upload

I am doing new version of old form and everything has worked great but I have problems with the old FileUpload tag. I am using jQuery Multiple File Upload Plugin as new upload style and it works great! Only problem is that if I delete old FileUpload element the new one doesn't work anymore. So my goal is to make form where user can choose files which will sent as attachment of an email. I have spent hours trying to figure out how this is even possible because I have deleted all references to this element from the c# file also. Does anybody have ideas?

```
<!-- PROBLEM STARTS-->
        <!-- if I delete or add Visible="false" attribute to the element the new upload system wont work anymore-->
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fuIssueAttachmentUppload" runat="server" Width="218px" EnableViewState="False"
            ViewStateMode="Disabled" />
        <!-- PROBLEM ENDS-->
        <p>
            <asp:Label ID="lblIssueAttachment" runat="server" Text="Attach file(s)"></asp:Label><br />
            <input type="file" class="multi" />
        </p>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="btnSend_Click" Width="290px"
            CausesValidation="False" />
```

This is the part where I attach the uploaded files to the email

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[i];
            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file.InputStream, file.FileName));
        }
```

Comment: A `<asp:FileUpload>` will render a `<input type="file">`. You can replace it with one of those if you don't need any server side interaction any more.

Comment: What do you mean? The point is that I dont want to use old <asp:FileUpload tag. I would like to use <input type="file" class="multi" /> which uses jquery multi file upload thingy :)

Comment: OK, so if you do this, can you explain exactly what "doesn't work".

Comment: I edited the main post. But yeah forgot to mention that it doesnt attach emails anymore if I delete <asp:FileUpload> element. So if i have old and new file upload elements the new element works. But if I have only the new element it wont work anymore. Is there away to test if files have been really requested or is it mail.Attachments bug?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesnt attach emails", do you get an error? Does Request.Files have any files in it? What exactly is different when it "doesn't work".

Comment: I checked Request.Files as you asked and yeah it doesn't jave any files in there when I have deleted the old asp fileupload elements. But when I dont delete old asp element Request.Files gives me right number of files. How is this possible? Does visual studio generate some weird code somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it! The new input tag didn't have runat-attribute. So only thing I had to do is to remove the old  tag and modify new upload tag to this:

```
<input runat="server" type="file" class="multi" />
```